# GSAP, move element up and down from Origin

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I have a "cookie" svg with a class of "cookie" , I want the cookie to start from origin and move to -20 and then move to 0 and them move to  20 and them move to 0, and I want it to do it infinite time , I am apparently using GSAP to do it using timeline, but can't figure out how to do it

```
tl.fromTo(".cookie", { y: 0 }, { y: 20 });
tl.fromTo(".cookie", { y: 20 }, { y: -20 });
tl.fromTo(".cookie", { y: -20 }, { y: 0 });
```

this code does the work but for one time only, But I want to do it infinite time so Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the animation infinitely, add `repeat: -1` to the timeline.

```js
let tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1 });

tl.to(".cookie", { y: -20, ease: "none" })
  .to(".cookie", { y: 0, ease: "none" })
  .to(".cookie", { y: 20, ease: "none" })
  .to(".cookie", { y: 0, ease: "none" });
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anushkachauhan/pen/eYKNaZj)

---

Also,

- Simply chaining `.to` gives the same result. So you don't have to use `.fromTo` each time.
- Adding `ease: "none"` made the animation less bumpy for me.